# Can you emulate a Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android Studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, samsung-galaxy

I've written a React Native app and need to test it on a Samsung Galaxy S10 emulator. When I look at the OSs available for Android Studio emulators, I don't see the S10. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Emulators deal with OS version, screen size, screen density. Unless you are using something really device specific (like foldable screen) pick what works for you. With AVDs you can get Google services pre-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Genymotion, you can find S10 and many other devices there.

And it's faster than AVD provided in Android Studio too.

Once downloaded, don't forget to install GApps to it.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ketan, thanks for the advice. Is there any disadvantage to Genymotion? Why would anyone still use Android Studio for emulation?

Comment: I personally prefer Genymotion over stock AVD, first, it's super-fast, many pre-configured devices, and is free for use. I haven't faced any limitations or problems per se yet.

Comment: One more time, after downloading the device image, don't forget to install GApps in it, they are very important as you might know it.